# Dimensional analysis / units for best fit curves

Tags: dimensional-analysis

I am doing a lot of curve fitting from experimental and modelling data.

If I have a polynomial of the form which takes a temperature T and outputs a pressure Pa

```
(Temp^2 + Temp + constant) = Pressure
```

then of course the units of left and right hand side of the equation do not match.

I need something like

```
(Temp^2 + Temp + constant)x = Pa
```

where x is a constant of proprtionality with the correct units.

(I am measuring temperture in Kelvin and pressure in pascals).
How does this work for ever higher order polynomials?

regards

Comment: `Temp^2 + Temp` This is dimensionally incorrect already.

Comment: dxiv - that is the entire point and hence the requirement for a constant of proportionality!

Comment: No, point is that *one* constant does not suffice, since $T$ and $T^2$ have different units, so adding them violates dimensional homogeneity in the first place. See the [posted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2719356/291201) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need a fitting curve like
$$
p = aT^2+bT+c
$$
with

- [c]=pressure
- [b]=pressure/temperature
- [a]=pressure/temperature^2